# How can I use Dragon Professional Individual along with Windows 10's text prediction feature?

Tags: windows-10, autocomplete, productivity, dragon-naturally-speaking, speech-to-text

I use the [text prediction feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2lhk.jpg) in Windows 10:

[image]

It seems to prevent Dragon Professional Individual 15.6 from transcribing my speech into the current field.

How can I use Dragon Professional Individual along with Windows 10's text prediction feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use Dragon Professional Individual along with Windows 10's text prediction feature. Those two programs are incompatible.